# Concern about struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm doing a project where our professor has given us code with variables and prototype declarations that we are unable to change. One is a struct, with a pointer to that struct is typedef'd as `pStudentRecord`:

```
typedef struct
{
  char* firstName;
  char* lastName;
  int id;
  float mark;
}* pStudentRecord;
```

With a pointer to this type called `g_ppRecords`. This will be a dynamic array of pointers to the structs above.

Here's where my question comes in. The records will be read from a file. If the filename specified doesn't exist then it creates a new one. I'm initializing the `g_ppRecords` pointer whenever the user adds the first new record:

```
if(!n) //where n = number of records
  g_ppRecords = (pStudentRecord*)  malloc(sizeof(pStudentRecord));

g_ppRecords[n] = (pStudentRecord) malloc(16);
```

This code works every time I've ran it so far, but I'm not sure how. If I add more records then a new pointer (`pStudentRecord`) will be created in the next position in `g_ppRecords`. By my understanding, I haven't allocated the space for that new pointer, yet every time it works without even a hint of a problem. I can access the members of the new structs fine and I'm not getting a heap corruption error or access violation or anything like that. Are my concerns correct or am I doubting myself?

Comment: You seem to only allocate space for one pointer, and only when `n` is zero. When `n` is nonzero, you don't allocate anything, so I'm confused as to how g_ppRecords gets set.

Comment: I am sorry that your professor has `typedef`ed a pointer.  It obscures the true memory layout of your program.  Anyway - your code is hard to understand.  1) `!n` should be `n == 0`.  2) You should never `malloc(16)`.  Only `malloc(sizeof(something))` or `malloc(arraySize * sizeof(something))`.

Comment: If you want to dynamically _reallocate_ something, like `g_ppRecords`, you should look intothe function `realloc`.

Comment: @pb2q Actually, please **stop** tagging questions with [tag:homework]. It's a dead tag and you're making work for those who are cleaning it up. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag/147125#comment421902_147125

Comment: @meager thanks, I'll review those meta posts

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code that you've shown, your concerns are valid.

This line:

```
g_ppRecords = (pStudentRecord*)  malloc(sizeof(pStudentRecord));
```

Allocates only enough space for a *single* `pStudentRecord`. Think of this as an array of `pStudentRecord` with only a single element, at `g_ppRecords[0]`.

> If I add more records then a new pointer (pStudentRecord) will be created in the next position in `g_ppRecords`.

Now the problem is what might happen when you do what you've described here. What happens when you add a new pointer? Unless you use `realloc` to get more space for `g_ppRecords`, you *don't* have room in that array for more pointers to records. If you `malloc` a new pointer at the second element, i.e.:

```
g_ppRecords[1] = (pStudentRecord) malloc(16);
```

Then you're using memory, `g_ppRecords[1]`, that you *haven't* allocated. This may *appear* to work, but this memory doesn't belong to you. Keep adding new pointers and eventually your program will break. Or your program may break because of something totally unrelated in another part of your code.

The fix is that you should initially allocate your array so that it can hold *multiple* pointers, instead of only one. How can you do this with your first `malloc` line?

I should add that when you allocate memory for a `struct` using `malloc(16)` you're making assumptions about the data structure that you shouldn't make, specifically that the `struct` will always occupy 16 bytes. Given your `typedef`: straight to a pointer from an anonymous `struct`, you can change that `16` to something more general, but this isn't directly related to your question, and is something that you should ask your professor about.

Comment: Ah, see for some reason `realloc` completely escaped me. You know when you get stuck on a problem and get tunnel visioned? Well I got stuck on wondering how it worked instead of fixing it in the first place. There is a lot of code and information missing from the question but you've completely opened my eyes and solved my problem. Thank you and to everyone for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, try to avoid `malloc( sizeof( type ))`, especially when the type is obfuscated by a typecast.  It is much safer to call sizeof on a variable: `malloc( sizeof x )`.  Also, in C, you should not cast the return from malloc.  In other words, instead of allocating space for only one record with:

```
g_ppRecords = (pStudentRecord*)  malloc(sizeof(pStudentRecord));
```

it would be better to allocate space for n records by writing:

```
g_ppRecords = malloc( n * sizeof *g_ppRecords );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct
{
  char* firstName;
  char* lastName;
  int id;
  float mark;
}* pStudentRecord;
```

This is an anonymous struct.  A bit weird here, but maybe to teach you something.  Do this to create a new one:

```
pStudentRecord ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

This will automatically malloc the right amount of memory.

You've still got problems because you need to malloc the array to hold the pointers.  For that do this:

```
pStudentRecord* g_ppRecords = malloc(n * sizeof(pStudentRecord));
```

You can then use g_ppRecords like this:

```
pStudentRecord ptr = g_ppRecords[3];
```

Putting it all together we have our custom allocator:

```
pStudentRecord* g_ppRecords = malloc(n * sizeof(pStudentRecord));

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  pStudentRecord ptr;
  g_ppRecords[i] = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
}
```

I wrote all this without compiling and testing, so there may be errors (but its not my homework :-) )

Comment: Yes the anonymous struct was intended to make us think but I hadn't encountered that before so I wasn't sure how to handle it. I would have thought that saying `sizeof(*ptr)` would have given me the sizeof a pointer to pStudentRecord, rather than what it points to. I'll give that a try instead. Thanks